# EF Lazy loading - how to return only specyfic values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Simple question - how can I return with lazy loading only specyfic elements of collection?

```
    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Attachments.Where(x => x.del != true) as ICollection<Attachment>;
        }
        set {
            this.Attachments = value;
        }
    }
```

I want to return only these `<Attachment>`, where `del != true`.

With this code, I have error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies
>
> Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack
>   overflow state.

Why? How can I do it?

Regards

Comment: `this.Attachments` refers to your `Attachments` property. It needs to call your `get` method. Which needs to call your `get` method. Which needs to call your `get` method. Get R#. It would have told you that the method is recursive on all paths.

Comment: You have to have a backing field here. Right now you're in an infinite recursion till the stack overflows.

Comment: ohhhh, its too early for me - I forgot to put `_Attachments` instead of `Attachments`.. Anyway thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments
{
    // defines get_Attachments
    get
    {
                    // calls get_Attachments
        return this.Attachments.Where(x => x.del != true) as ICollection<Attachment>;
    }
```

Your `get_Attachments` method is recursive on all paths. The method will be called until the stack overflows. [This video should help you to visualise the events leading up to the stack overflowing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnHmskwqCCQ).

It appears you don't have [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). [ReSharper has a check for these kinds of mistakes](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5319611). You should install the trial.